# Finding size of types passed via command line argument

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program to which the type like int char is passed through command-line argument and then `sizeof` is used to print the bytes

I have written the partial code and if someone can complete how and what to write inside `sizeof`

if I write `argv[loop]` it is a problem as that is a string and not a type

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 if (argc > 1) {
  for (int loop = 1; loop <= argc; loop++) {
     printf("%s bytes are %d", argv[loop], sizeof)
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `loop < argc` for starters.

Comment: `loop <=argc` --> `loop < argc`, I believe.

Comment: `sizeof` what BTW?

Comment: C is *statically typed*, i.e. all types are known at compilation time as well as their sizes (except for VLAs, but that's not revelant), so `sizeof` wont help you.

Comment: I assume he wants the number of bytes for each string in the array.  Perhaps looking for `strlen`?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons probably. Still, very unclear and not compiling. `strlen` does the job then.

Comment: C does not have a string type. That code is so broken in various aspects, it should be clear there are basics missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof` can't help you here. Because you will just get `sizeof(char*)` that's it nothing else.

Well it's all getting an array of `char*` so each of them will be a `char*` and alas there is no way you can know if it is `int` or `float` directly. Because all you get is null terminated `char` array for each of the arguments.

If you want to know how long the each argument string is then use `strlen()`.

And hey if you need someway to store get that information I can tell you a scheme

```
./a.out -f 1.32 -i 123 -s "ok"
```

Now you know `-f` means you will expect a `float`. Parse it accordingly and be happy. You have to design the program like that though.

**If your intention is this**

```
./a.out int char
```

Then you will print `sizeof` `int` and `char` well then there is no way to do that.

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, **which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type**. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
>   the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
>   is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
>   is an integer constant.

Well here it is none of them if we pass the null terminated string ("int", "float" to `sizeof`). So this won't work.

Comment: I think that this doesn't answer the question. As I understand it, the OP wants to run `prog int char` to output the values of `sizeof int` and `sizeof char`.

Comment: "*there is no type information*" there is: all arguments passed to a C program "arrive" as `0`-terminated `char`-array, aka  "string".

Comment: @alk.: Yes that's right but no information regarding what type that char array mean..but sure will give a clean edit.

Comment: @Jens.: I will edit the answer then and wil try to answer.

Comment: @Jens.: You can check I edited.